# How to get edited value from FCK Editor when FCK Editor placed inside a Update Panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, fckeditor

i am developing a site, as i have to upload an image and a per-coded content in a FCK Editor as a mail sending tool in my site. during a click event there a data loss in the image upload. So, i added the FCK Editor in a update panel.But after adding it in updated panel the data loss is solved, but FCK Editor not getting the edited value from the per-coded content.
Can anybody please help to solve this problem.
thanks in advance..

Comment: what is per-coded content? i cant get you man...

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem try this and see if it helps.

Put it in your page load so that it will run each time the page loads.  It think it requires that you are using the .net server control component.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(
PageContentUpper.GetType(),
"PageContentUpper",
"try{FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance('" + fckEditor1.ClientID + "').UpdateLinkedField();}catch(err){}");
```

If it works make sure to mark correct or people might stop trying to help you ;)
Hope it helps.